# How to read response header of a ajax post call of empty response body

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, response-headers

I am making a ajax post call that returns the required information in the response header an the empty response body . I am using the following code to make call

```
$.ajax({
  url : someUrl,
  type : "post",
  contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",    
  success : function(data, textStatus, request)
  {
        alert("success");
  },
  error : function(request, textStatus, errorThrown)
  {
        alert("error");     
  },
  timeout : "150000"
});
```

i always get error alert since the response is empty even though the status is 200 ok. Is there any workaround for the calls like this?

Answer (score 0):

For example, we want to get `Date` header from the URL which returns error:

```
var get = $.get('http://stackoverflow.com/asdasdasddsadsadasde').always(function(){
    alert(get.getResponseHeader('Date'));
});
```

`success` and `error` methods are deprecated in latest versions of jQuery. You may use `done`, `fail` and `always` methods.